# Multiple Independent Axis

Tags: highcharts

Hia, I'm trying to set up a graph as shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tXz73/

Essentially a higher / lower, percentage stacked chart, and then an index chart on the right hand axis (not % based)

I'm having a problem that the data in "index" seems to be affecting the scale of the stacking column charts?

I've set

```
yAxis: 1
```

but this doesn't seem to be isolating the series?

Is there a flag I can set to stop this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got it!
In the chart setup:

```
alignTicks: false,
```

this unlinks the 2 axes, then:

```
gridLineWidth: 0,
```

Within the second y-axis definition keeps the chart tidy!